# Retrieving files from different paths in Python?

Tags: python, path

I am building a Python wrapper for a command line program. The wrapper takes a series of files and sends them one-by-one to the command line program as arguments. My wrapper looks like this:

```
for file_name in glob.iglob('A0*'):
    output_dir = ''.join(('my_output_',file_name))
    cmd = ['/Users/bunsen/src/my_program', file_name]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
```

I'm having some difficulty understanding how to control file paths. I have a very long list of file names that my command line program has to iterate through. Currently, my wrapper works perfectly IF the files are in the same directory as my Python script.

I would like to store the command line argument files in a separate sub-directory and access this sub-directory as a relative path with Python. How can I add code to my program that will allow Python to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is the following: `glob.iglob(os.getcwd()+'/A0*')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module to get at some useful (and platform independent) pathname functions. You might try something like:

```
import os
COMMAND_LINE_FILES_HOME = "cmd_files" # Set the name of the directory where the command line files live
BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # gets the path to the directory where this file lives

COMMAND_LINE_FILES_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, COMMAND_LINE_FILES_HOME) # Join these paths in a system-neutral way
```

Now you can use COMMAND_LINE_FILES_DIRECTORY when you open your files. You could get a list of the files in that directory and iterate through them (using, as Carlos suggests above, glob.iglob(pathname)), or whatever you want.